# how i can get ebay review for each product?

Tags: php, dom

I want to show product review for each ebay product using api.

I am using this

```
 $api_url = "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindReviewsAndGuides&responseencoding=XML&appid=" . $ebay_appID . "&siteid=0&version=515&ProductID.type=Reference&ProductID.value=272548628297";
```

but getting this error

```
   2017-02-08T09:52:38.252Z
   Failure

    Invalid Product ID.
    ProductID is not valid. Supported types are Reference, ISBN, UPC and EAN. Value should be a valid product reference ID or external product ID value.
    10.19
    Error
    RequestError

   E957_CORE_APILW2_17860840_R1
   957
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: ***aliexpress*** or ***ebay***?

Comment: @smuuf actually i want to get review on both aliexpress and ebay products